# removing and adding a class based on position within an array Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I am creating a blog page using angular 5 where each of the blog posts have the class:

```
col-md-4
```

However, what I want is the latest blog post (i.e the first on the page) to have the class of :`col-md-12`.

The html that I have is as follows:

```
                <div *ngFor="let blog of blogs" class="blog-posts col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
                    <img class="blog-img" (click)="goToBlogDetailsPage(blog.sys.id)"src="{{blog.fields.blogimage.fields.file.url}}" class="rounded" alt="">
          <div class="info">
            <h3 class="author">{{blog.fields.authorInfo}}</h3>
                            <h2  (click)="goToBlogDetailsPage(blog.sys.id)" class="title">{{blog.fields.title}}</h2>
            <p class="short-desc" > {{blog.fields.desciption}}</p>
            <img (click)="goToBlogDetailsPage(blog.sys.id)" class="sml-logo" src="/assets/img/logos/logo_blue.png" alt="">

            <!-- <button (click)="goToBlogDetailsPage(blog.sys.id)"class="btn btn-info">Open Blog Post</button> -->
          </div>
        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I have tried accessing the index of the `array[0]` however I can not seem to alter the styling on just the first item, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use index and ternary operator to set the class

```
<div *ngFor="let blog of blogs; let ind = index" class="blog-posts"
  [ngClass]="ind === 0 ? 'col-md-12' : 'col-md-4'" >
```

Comment: <div [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let blog of blogs; var i = index" class="blog-posts"
          ng-class="i === 0 ? 'col-md-12"): ng:///PagesModule/BlogPageComponent.html@25:10
Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 28 in [let blog of blogs; var i = index] in ng:///PagesModule/BlogPageComponent.html@25:10 ("lass="i === 0 ? 'col-md-12' : 'col-md-4'">

Comment: Just realised that i need let instead of var, however now all blog posts have the class of col-md-12 and none have the class of col-md-4

Comment: using [ngClass] instead of ng-class did it for me, just incase anyone else is having the same problem!